# Правило RewriteRule работает частично

Tags: .htaccess, mod_rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^users/([0-9]+)/profile[/]?$ profile.php?uid=$1 [L]
```

По такому правилу почему-то работает http://localhost/users/135/profile**.**  Хотя я хочу, чтобы работало только либо если после profile ничего нет, либо слеш. Не подскажете, что не так?

UPD:
Из http://localhost/users/135/profile сделать profile.php?uid=135 
Из http://localhost/users/135/profile/ сделать profile.php?uid=135(да, одинаково)
Из http://localhost/users/135/profile. должна получаться ошибка(другая страница, не profile.php)
Из http://localhost/users/135/profile, должна получаться ошибка(другая страница, не profile.php)
Из http://localhost/users/135/profile/84 должна получаться ошибка(другая страница, не profile.php)

по написанному мной выше правилу работает всё правильно, кроме третьей строки(с точкой),  она ссылается на profile.php, хотя должно выдавать ошибку.

Comment: @Dazar Пожалуйста, распишите на примере url-а, что есть и что нужно получить.

К примеру, как здесь:

[Rewrite nginx с картинки на страницу][1] 


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/181631/mod_rewrite-rewrite-nginx-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83

Comment: Добавил пример.

Comment: Может быть так должно быть?  

    RewriteRule ^users/([0-9]+)/profile/?$ profile.php?uid=$1 [L]
Просто регулярное выражение у Вас задает адреса вида  
http://localhost/profile/135/uid  
а результат Вы хотите получить от:  
http://localhost/users/135/profile

Comment: Да, конечно, это была моя опечатка, исправил в вопросе, однако большой роли она не играет. Я спрашиваю именно про случай, когда в конце адреса стоит точка. По идее он не подходит под написанное мной правило, однако сервер и его переделывает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/users/(\d+)/profile/?$
RewriteRule ^ profile.php?uid=%1 [L]
```

У меня работает нормально.